# How to make msysgit 'find' higher-priority than Windows 'find'?

Tags: windows, path

With Git for Windows installed, I have two "find" programs on my computer:

```
λ where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\find.exe
```

How do I make the Git's `find` being the preferred one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to **before** `C:\Windows\System32\` in your `PATH`. Executables are searched for under each entry in `PATH` in order until it finds the first match.